neovim making snippets write in lua with nvim_set_keymap
i want to set keymap for lua to be sinppets for example:
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<leader>rs", ":call append(line('.'),  [[welcome]])<CR>")

and now i want to make sinppets for react component
const welcome = => (
  <>
    <p> welcome </p>
  </>
);
export default welcome;

i try to make the sinppets but its not working very well:
--
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap(
  "n",
  "<leader>rs",
  [[ <cmd>call append(line('.'), 'const welcome = () => {')<CR>
    <cmd>normal! o<CR>
    '\treturn (')<CR>
    <cmd>normal! o<CR>
     '\t\t<>\')<CR>
    <cmd>normal! o<CR>
    '\t\t\twelcome')<CR>
    <cmd>normal! o<CR>
    '\t\t</>\')<CR>
    <cmd>normal! o<CR>
    '}\')<CR>
    <cmd>normal! o<CR>
    'export default welcome;')<CR> ]],
  { noremap = true, silent = true }
)

i just want to help to know how to write remap for  snippets not for react only !!
